# Why does Heroku always find unresolved dependencies?

Tags: deployment, rubygems, heroku

I haven't installed any gems since the last time I deployed, but
Heroku keeps thinking there is something new I suppose, and that
significantly slows down my deployment time. How can I make sure that
I don't get this message?

EDIT:

This is from my deployment message. I dunno...is it normal?

```
Writing objects: 100% (13/13), 1.88 KiB, done.
Total 13 (delta 10), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Heroku receiving push
-----> Rails app detected
-----> Detected Rails is not set to serve static_assets
       Installing rails3_serve_static_assets... done
-----> Gemfile detected, running Bundler version 1.0.7
       Unresolved dependencies detected; Installing...
       Using --without test:development:staging
       Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I contacted support and they resolved it.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ git add Gemfile.lock
$ git commit -m "We should always check in Gemfile.lock in our applications."
$ git push heroku master
```

Comment: My Gemfile.lock was already commited, and I get "no changes checked in" message when I commit that.

Comment: Could it be because Heroku uses --without test:development
flag?